make sure TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory
Anils-MacBook-Pro:~ anilkotangale$ tesseract /Users/anilkotangale/Desktop/new.png test5 -l jpn_vert
Error opening data file /usr/local/share/tessdata/jpn_vert.traineddata
Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory.
Failed loading language 'jpn_vert'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
Could not initialize tesseract.your text
Anils-MacBook-Pro:~ anilkotangale$ tesseract /Users/anilkotangale/Desktop/new.png test5 -l jpn_vert
Error opening data file /usr/local/share/tessdata/jpn_vert.traineddata
Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory.
Failed loading language 'jpn_vert'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
Could not initialize tesseract.
